# duplicate specific rows of a dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

hi I have the following data frame

```
  weather     day      month       activity
  sunny     Monday     April      go for cycling
  raining   Friday     December   stay home
```

what I want is to duplicate the rows by 5 times without taking into account the activity column

so the output should be

```
weather     day      month       activity
 sunny     Monday     April      go for cycling
 sunny     Monday     April
 sunny     Monday     April
 sunny     Monday     April
 sunny     Monday     April
 raining   Friday     December   stay home
 raining   Friday     December
 raining   Friday     December
 raining   Friday     December
 raining   Friday     December
 raining   Friday     December
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for repeated rows and then replace duplicated `activity` by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(5)]
df['activity'] = df['activity'].mask(df.index.duplicated(), '')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   weather     day     month        activity
0    sunny  Monday     April  go for cycling
1    sunny  Monday     April                
2    sunny  Monday     April                
3    sunny  Monday     April                
4    sunny  Monday     April                
5  raining  Friday  December       stay home
6  raining  Friday  December                
7  raining  Friday  December                
8  raining  Friday  December                
9  raining  Friday  December
```

Comment: with this code the activity column is also duplicated 5 times

Comment: @loutsi1 - yes, in pandas not possible 2 rows there.

Comment: @loutsi1 - in pandas each DataFrame has columns with same length, so here all columns has length `10`.

Comment: yes I saw what you saying. So now have 10 values on the other columns and two values on the activity column. The remaining rows of the activity column are fulfilling with nan values?

Comment: @loutsi1 - No, here are repalced by empty string defined by `.mask(df.index.duplicated(), '')`, if need missing value use `.mask(df.index.duplicated(), np.nan)`